# Multiple button click event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-6

I have a form, and there is a button. Onclick of the button, I am doing some DB insert operation.

But on LIVE server, the value get inserted twice. On other test server it work fine. All server have same code.

Button code:

```
<asp:button id="uiSave" cssclass="formbutton" runat="server" text="Add Text"></asp:button>


 Private Sub uiSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles uiSave.Click
        If Page.IsValid Then
            TemplateTranslation.AddTemplateTranslation(uiContent.Text, uiLanguage.SelectedItem.Value, _TemplateID, Request.Form("uiBody"), uiSubject.Text)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Rendered Html code

```
<input id="AddTemplateTranslationUC1_uiSave" class="formbutton" type="submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("AddTemplateTranslationUC1$uiSave", "", true, "", "", false, false))" value="Add Text" name="AddTemplateTranslationUC1$uiSave">
```

The issue is in all browser.

Comment: do you hitting F5 after button click???

Comment: On the top of your page do you have autowhireevents=true? if yes, set to false and try again

Comment: Yes, AutoEventWireup="false" already set to false.